# Sencha Touch List Not Displaying Data

Tags: extjs

I am using the following code to display list but it shows empty cells.

```
Ext.define('CodeCamp.view.Home',{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'home',
    config:
    {
        title:"Home",
        iconCls:'home',
        layout:'fit',
        items:[

        {
            xtype:'list',
            store:'CodeCamps',
            data:[
            {title:'Ssssss'},
            {title:'sssadasd'},
            {title:'asdasdasd'}

            ],
            itemTpl:'{title}'

        }


        ]

    }
})
```

It shows three rows (equal to the number of items in the data array). But seems like itemTpl has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have both store and data properties on the list. Either remove the store and just work off the raw data property (no model, no fields, absolutely basic memory datastore), or turn the store into an object and put the data (along with the fields) in there. For example:

```
store: {
    fields: ['title'],
    data: [{ 
        title: 'Title 1'
    },{ 
        title: 'Title 2'
    },{ 
        title: 'Title 3'
    }]
}
```

If you are trying to add a store based on alias, you would want to use the property *type* inside a store object.